# Existem técnicas para reduzir o uso de memória (por parte do desenvolvimento) quanto ao uso do javascript?

Tags: javascript, desempenho, memória

Eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma técnica para reduzir o uso de memória quanto ao uso do javascript. Digo, quanto ao desenvolvimento.

Notei que uma determinada página que estamos desenvolvendo onde trabalho parece utilizar muita memória, e isso é sinalizado no google chrome como sendo maior parte desse consumo vindo do javascript.

Como poderia solucionar isso?

Comment: Wallace, levando em conta o seu histórico, vou dizer algo que acredito que já esta fazendo: tente diminuir o numero de consultas aos elementos da pagina, reduza o numero de funções em memoria, você pode alcançar isto declarando os mesmos no inicio do escopo.

Comment: Não saberia por onde começar esta resposta. Mas certamente o problema ocorre porque está mantendo objetos demais ativos por mais tempo do que realmente é necessário.

Comment: @bigown, por exemplo, a minha aplicação carrega posts sob demana (inifinite scroll). Parece que a cada "rolada" de mouse, a memória só vai aumentando absurdamente quanto ao consumo

Comment: Primeiro, quando você carrega muita coisa, é normal que o consumo vai aumentando. Não existe milagre. Mas certamente tem jeitos certos de fazer isto para não haver desperdício e maneiras em que duplica ou multiplica dados sem necessidade. Aí já começamos entrar em situações específicas.

Comment: Tente usar mais javascript puro(não sei se é seu caso de estar usando muito jQuery) para operações mais simples, como loops por ex. De uma atenção à como você cria eventos a grande grupos de elementos ou como você manipula estes elementos, esse tipo de coisa.

Answer (score 0):

Isso é um problema de arquitetura. O que eu faria é fazer uma nova etapa de levantamento de requisitos. Pode ser que há eventos aonde há desperdício de funções, objetos, etc. Tente fazer requisições via GET para aplicação receber somente as funções que necessita. Tome cuidado ao fazer uso de carregamento em JSON.
Tomando cuidados mais simples do que parece, não vai sobrecarregar o hardware na hora da aplicação.